# Session passing failed - Servlets

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, session-variables

The following are my two servlets where I want to pass my session.

The problem is the session passing is done when its navigating to the SuccessPage servlet, but not when its going to the Failure servlet.

**Login servlet `doGet()` method:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    
ServletException, IOException{
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String userName=request.getParameter("userName");
    String userPass=request.getParameter("userPassword");
    String userRePass=request.getParameter("userRePassword");
    try{
        String query="Select VendorName from vendorinfo where VendorPass=?";
        connection1=Connection_Class.getInstance().getConnection();
        ptmt=connection1.prepareStatement(query);
        ptmt.setString(1,userPass);
        rs=ptmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()&& userName.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("VendorName"))){
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("loggedVendor",rs.getString(1));
        //this is working fine...im able to get the userName in the next servlet
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=context.getRequestDispatcher("/SuccessPage");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        }
        else{  //this is not working .....whats the problem here ?
            request.setAttribute("wrongUser",userName);
            ServletContext context=getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher=context.getRequestDispatcher("/Failure");
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Failure servlet `doGet()` method:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  
ServletException, IOException {
/*all i want to do here is that I want to get the userName from the previous servlet but its 
not displaying that and its displaying null */
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("<body bgcolor=#F3EEF0><h1>");
    out.println("<center>");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
    out.println("This is a failure page");
    out.println(session.getAttribute("wrongUser"));
    out.println("</center></h1></body>");
}
```

Is there something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the data with key "wrongUser" in request and not session in the first servlet:

```
 request.setAttribute("wrongUser",userName);
```

and retrieving it from session in the Failure Servlet:

```
session.getAttribute("wrongUser");
```

Use the either "session" in both the places or "request" in both places.  So if you use request.setAttribute() use request.getAttribute().  If you use session.setAttribute(), use session.getAttribute().

Recommendation: Use request, so that you do not start loading the session unnecessarily with a lot of arbitrary.  You do not need this value beyond the scope of this request/response cycle.